# How does the divergence of the Coulomb field "blow up" at origin?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, singularities

Many sources (DJ Griffiths, other answers on stack exchange) claim that the divergence of the vector field $\vec E=\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$, $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec E$ "blows up" at $\vec r=0$. But upon computation, we get an expression like $\frac{0}{r^2}$, which means it is 0 everwhere except origin, and at origin it is$\frac{0}{0}$ (undefined). The limit as $r \to 0$ also is 0. What exactly does "blow up" mean, are they implying it goes to infinity as $r \to 0$ ? Is there a way to prove this. If they do imply it goes to infinity, are they implying infinity is $\frac{0}{0}$ ?

Comment: Do you a) know that $\nabla \cdot E = 4\pi\delta(r)$ and b) understand why people often say that the $\delta$-function goes to infinity at $r=0$?

Comment: A)I have seen the proof that you have given in the h-bar chat, there, he implies that the integral "action" property of the divergence on a test function implies that its the dirac delta (and that its 0 everywhere else), B) but I am not sure if its a definition, or a derived theorem about the delta function that it goes to infinity as r goes to 0.

Comment: This is really about mathematics. How do we deal with limits of functions that have a non-trivial integral (in this case the charge) but are zero almost everywhere? Look for mathematical textbooks on "functional analysis" for that. As mentioned by the other comments, physicists are glazing over the details and roll everything into a magical entity called  the δ-function. That works fine for some of the calculations in electrostatics and electrodynamics, until you are asking questions about self-energy. And then it blows up, too. Physically it just means that "it just can't be so".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [definition of the divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Definition) of a vector field $\vec{E}(\vec{r})$
is the limit of the surface integral per volume:
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{E}(\vec{r}_0)=
\lim_{V\to 0}\frac{\oint_{\partial V\text{ around }\vec{r}_0} \vec{E}(\vec{r})\cdot d\vec{S}}{V}$$

For the Coulomb field the surface integral around the origin
($\vec{r}_0=\vec{0}$) is
$$\oint_{\partial V\text{ around }\vec{0}} \vec{E}(\vec{r})\cdot d\vec{S}= 4\pi,$$
which is independent on how big or small the volume $V$ is.
Hence the divergence is infinite at the origin:
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{E}(\vec{0})=\lim_{V\to 0}\frac{4\pi}{V} = \infty$$

Comment: I'm embarassed that I didn't think of the d*mn definition of divergence ! Thank you